# Represent sum of two real numbers as a product

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Is it possible to find functions $f,g:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $a+b=f(a)*g(b)$ holds for all $a,b\in[0,1]$?

Comment: Do you mean $f(a)f(b)=f(a)+f(b)$?

Comment: @Bacon No, i don't mean that.

Comment: Taking $a=b=0$ we see that $f(0)\times g(0)=0$ so at least one of $f(0),g(0)=0$.  But that leads to a contradiction.

Comment: Then I'm not so sure you will get anything other than a contradiction.

Comment: By a remarkable result of Kolmogorov (see Kolmogorov networks), any real-valued continuous function can be represented by the composition of unary functions and the binary addition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

---

Assume that two such functions exist. Then set $a=b=0$ and you see that $f(0)\cdot g(0)=0$. This tells you that one of the two numbers must be $0$. WLOG, let's say $f(0)=0$.

Then, $$1= 0+1 = f(0)\cdot g(1) = 0\cdot g(1) = 0$$

Contradiction.

---

(the WLOG really did not lose any generality, because if $g(0)=0$, then the same contradiction can be acchieved by setting $1=1+0$)